# Reference and Bound Object

Tags: c++, reference

I read in Lippman et al that there is no way to rebind a reference to a different object (p59)

It sees to me that the code below does just that and doesnt produce any error in VC Express 2010

Can someone pls explain to me what's happening.

Many Thanks,

Paolo

```
void demo()
{

int i = 5;
int k = 5;
int& ir1 = i;
int& ir2 = k;
ir2 = i;
}


void main()  {
  demo();

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code isn't rebinding anything. It's just assigning a new value to what the `ir2` reference is bound to.

Comment: @Mat; great - I thought rebinding meant reassigning. Can you pelase elaborate ehat rebing means?

Comment: @RandomCPlusPlus it means that you can't do this: &ir2=&i     this will tell you that &ir2 is not a modifiable lvalue.

Comment: `ir2` is bound to `k`, so both `ir2` and `k` refer to the same integer object. `ir2 = i` or `k = i` just change the value of that object, to whatever `i`'s value happens to be at the time.

Comment: @PeterT - I now get the difference between rebinding and re-assigning. Thanks for that!

Comment: @DeadMG: thanks. @RandomCPlusPlus: rebinding a reference (if it was possible) would mean making it "point at" another object. In your example, you could try to/want to make `ir2` (that is bound to `k`) point to `i` so that `ir2 = 123` would change `i` and not `k` - this is not possible. Once `ir2` is bound to `k`, you can't change that relationship.

Comment: Actually, you *can* rebind a reference. You cannot do it portably, and you cannot do it without getting very down and dirty, but it can be done. The ability to rebind references is needed, for example, in some application-side checkpoint/restart capabilities.